# Calcular raices de una funcion cuadratica

Tags: c++, c

Necesito calcular raices de una ecuación cuadratica  dando los tres valores compila pero sin embargo, me da como resultado nan    porque da resultado numero negativo y no logro pasar a un resultado que no sea nan. como podria hacerlo? gracias.

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include<math.h>
 using namespace std;
int main (){
float A, B, C;
float e,f,g;
float s1, s2, s3;
int num;
float ecuacion;
float nr;

cout<<"Introduzca el valor de a:"<<endl;
cin>>A;
cout<<"Introduzca valor de b: "<<endl;
cin>>B;
cout<<"Introduzca valor de c:"<<endl;
cin>>C;
nr=((B*B)-(4*A*C));

if(A==0 && B==0 && C==0){
    cout<<"La ecuacion no tiene solución"<<endl;
    
}
if( A>0 && B>0&& C>0){
    e=(-B+sqrt(nr));
    f=(-B-sqrt(nr));
    g=2*A;
    s1=e/g;
    s2=f/g;
    

    cout<<"El primer resultado es:"<<s1;
    
    cout<<"El segundo resultado es: "<<s2;
    
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando `nr` es negativo? ¿Por qué estás comprobando `if( A>0 && B>0&& C>0)`?

Comment: porque se supone que deben ingresar por pantalla solo numeros mayor a 0, eso le debo decir al que ingrese los digitos